# avahi-daemon gets stuck registering a service I'm publishing with avahi-publish-service

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bonjour, avahi

Occasionally, I notice that I can't detect services that I'm publishing via avahi (bonjour) on Ubuntu. For example, avahi-browse -a does not show the published service, and the browser does not resolve the published .local hostname. On the server side, I noticed the output of `ps` suggests that `avahi-daemon` is getting stuck registering the service:

```
ubuntu@node3:~$ ps aux | grep [a]vahi
root     26584  0.0  0.0   4204   356 ?        S    19:21   0:00 supervise avahi
ubuntu   26598  0.0  0.0   4216   352 ?        S    19:21   0:00 multilog s8388608 n10 /var/log/avahi
avahi    28332  0.0  0.0  32352  1636 ?        S    20:19   0:00 avahi-daemon: registering [node3-44.local]
avahi    28333  0.0  0.0  32224   468 ?        S    20:19   0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
root     28338  0.0  0.0  17192  1028 ?        S    20:19   0:00 avahi-publish-service -as node3 _foobar._tcp 8080
```

Here's what the output of this command looks like on an "unstuck" host:

```
ubuntu@node2:~$ ps aux | grep [a]vahi
root     26501  0.0  0.0   4204   356 ?        S    19:21   0:00 supervise avahi
ubuntu   26527  0.0  0.0   4216   352 ?        S    19:21   0:00 multilog s8388608 n10 /var/log/avahi
avahi    29418  0.0  0.0  32484  1632 ?        S    20:12   0:00 avahi-daemon: running [node2.local]
avahi    29419  0.0  0.0  32224   464 ?        S    20:12   0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
root     29425  0.0  0.0  17192  1032 ?        S    20:12   0:00 avahi-publish-service -as node2 _foobar._tcp 8080
```

I did see this old [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=450369), which could be related. Sometimes killing `avahi-daemon` seems to fix the problem temporarily. Also, one attempt at rebooting a stuck machine worked. However, I'd like to understand why this is happening and how I can deal with the problem in the most robust way possible. Any ideas?

Comment: I suffered from the same problem earlier, until added `allow-interfaces=` in avahi-daemon.conf.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that ticket 201 has been around for some while on the Avahi site.  Though I couldn't even register there...  Looks like development on this project has fallen off.  We experienced a similar problem.  The below addressed it (for us):

```
    diff --git a/avahi-core/server.c b/avahi-core/server.c
    index 69a1d02..03d4fc1 100644
    --- a/avahi-core/server.c
    +++ b/avahi-core/server.c
    @@ -1216,8 +1216,8 @@ static void register_browse_domain(AvahiServer *s) {
     static void register_stuff(AvahiServer *s) {
         assert(s);

    -    server_set_state(s, AVAHI_SERVER_REGISTERING);
         s->n_host_rr_pending ++; /** Make sure that the state isn't changed tp AVAHI_SERVER_RUNNING too early */
    +    server_set_state(s, AVAHI_SERVER_REGISTERING);

         register_hinfo(s);
         register_browse_domain(s);
```

Comment: Can you tell me how widely you've tested this? Would help with integrating the patch. https://github.com/lathiat/avahi/issues/7

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and wrote a [patch](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/avahi/2014-March/002291.html) which addressed the issue for me.

In a [follow up](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/avahi/2014-March/002292.html), I related the patch to bug 201.

Update:

I have been running a patched version of the avahi daemon for more than a year on several devices. The devices are often restarted, disconnected/reconnected to the network. The devices never got stuck registering after applying the patch and we did not experience any strange side effects.